# Cleaning up unclosed ZipFile for archive in excel file

Tags: java, excel, maven, selenium, pom.xml

So I've been working on a simple automation framework that uses excel as data pool. However, while updating the version of my pom.xlm, I've encountered this error in my console.

`Cleaning up unclosed ZipFile for archive C:<workspace repo>\ExcelFile.xlsx`

I have no idea what went wrong. This error does not stop the execution and my tests run smoothly. How can I possibly solve this problem. I can't find anything related to this.

Here are the dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-contrib</artifactId>
        <version>3.7-beta3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>4.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity-dep</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
        <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.ashot</groupId>
        <artifactId>ashot</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports-testng-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here's the method I deal with the excel:

```
public static String get(String sheetName, String scenario, String columnName) throws IOException {

        org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook tempWB;
        int k=0;
        try {

            if(workbookPath.contains(".xlsx") || workbookPath.contains(".xlsm")){
                tempWB = new XSSFWorkbook(workbookPath);
            } else{             
                InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(workbookPath);
                tempWB = (org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook) new HSSFWorkbook(new POIFSFileSystem(inp));                 
            }

            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet sheet = tempWB.getSheet(sheetName);

            int rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

            for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
                //Getting the number of defined cells in the row
                int cols = sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();

                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) { 
                    if(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j,Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).toString().replace(".0", "").equalsIgnoreCase(columnName)){ 
                        k=j;
                    }

                    map.put(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0,Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).toString().replace(".0", ""),
                            sheet.getRow(i).getCell(k,Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).toString().replace(".0", ""));
                }
            } 
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 

        return map.get(scenario);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I added `tempWB.close();`  and the error disappears! :)

Answer (score 9):

I could notice that you haven't closed your InputStream. If you do not close the stream, file will be locked until inputstream has been closed or JVM is shutdown.

So probably, the easiest thing in your context above is to auto-close by using a try-with-resources construct as,

```
try (FileInputStream inp = new FileInputStream(workbookPath)) {
    tempWB = (org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook) new HSSFWorkbook(new POIFSFileSystem(inp)); 
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.error("Class Utils | Method setExcelFile | Exception desc : "+ e.getMessage());
}
```

Hope it helps you. :)

Comment: It prints `Class Utils | Method setExcelFile | Exception desc : The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
TestString`

Comment: I added `tempWB.close();` and the error disappears! :)